# Best way to call a function in specific time in django

Tags: django, time

in my django project i have a model `Task` :

```
class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    expiration_date = models.DateTimeField(default=max_expiration_date)

####################################

def max_expiration_date():
    now = timezone.now()
    return now + timezone.timedelta(days=7)
```

exact in expiration date i need call `notification` function.please be notice i will have too many `Task` instance so i need the best method for optimal system consumption.what is best way to do that? `celery` can do this?thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Celery function `apply_async` can take an argument `eta` to specify a datetime after which the task should be run.

> Note: The task is guaranteed to be executed at some time after the specified date and time, but not necessarily at that exact time.

With this you can just pass your `expiration_date` as the `eta` parameter calling the `apply_async` on your `notification` within the initial task creation.

Documentation: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#eta-and-countdown