# celery not working in django and just waiting (pending)

Tags: django, celery

i'm trying found how celery is working. i have a project that have about 10 app.now i want use celery .

setting.py:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://rabbitmq:rabbitmq@localhost:5672/rabbitmq_vhost'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost'
```

i created a user in rabbitmq with this info:`username: rabbitq` and `password:rabbitmq` . then i create a vhost with name `rabbitmq_vhost`  and add `rabbitmq` permission to it. all is fine i think because all of error about rabbitmq disappear .

here is my test.py:

```
from .task import when_task_expiration

def test_celery():
    result = when_task_expiration.apply_async((2, 2), countdown=3)
    print(result.get())
```

task.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import logging

from celery import shared_task
from proj.celery import app

@app.task
def when_task_expiration(task, x):
    print(task.id, 'task done')
    return True
```

celery.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')

app = Celery('proj')

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

now when i call `test_celery()` in python shell it's pending.i try to replace `@shared_task` and `@app.task(bind=True)` but noting changed.even i try use `.delay()` instead `apply_async((2, 2), countdown=3)` and again nothing happend.

i'm trying to use celery to call a function in specific time during [this quesation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56928636/best-way-to-call-a-function-in-specific-time-in-django/) that i ask in past.thank you.

Comment: Are you running the celery worker in command line as well?

Comment: thank you for reply.no i don't do anything else just above code and calling function in shell.what i must do now?

Comment: i'm adding `celery.py` to question too maybe help.thank you

Comment: Run `celery worker --app=<app_name>.celery --loglevel=DEBUG --concurrency=1` to start the celery worker

Comment: Do not call print() in your task. Use the celery logger instead... Also, it is not `blind=True` but `bind=True`...

Comment: @GauravWaghmare. thank you master . i use same command `celery -A project worker -l info` and its working now. you saved my days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You most likely forgot to run at least one Celery worker process. To do so, execute the following in the shell: `celery worker -A proj.celery -c 4 -l DEBUG` (here I assumed your Celery application is defined in proj/celery.py as you have `Celery('proj')` in there)